# Neo4j -CASE statement-Create a node if it doesn't exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to check if a user has made a post before.
If he had made a post ,`post_id` will be `max(post_id)+1`.
Else `post_id` will be `1`.
Cypher query is below:

```
MATCH (p:Post{user_id:1})
with count(p) as c
CASE 
WHEN c>0
THEN create (cc:Post{user_id:1,post:1})
ELSE with max(p.post_id+1) as new_post_id create (cc:Post{user_id:1,post:new_post_id}) END;
```

It produces the following error:

```
Invalid input 'S': expected 'l/L' (line 4, column 3 (offset: 48))
"CASE"
```

How to solve it?
Is there a better way to find whether a node with particular property exists and do operations based on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a second WITH statement to set the proper `post_id` depending on the case.

Modified query:

```
MATCH (p:Post{user_id:1})
WITH count(p) as c, max(p.post) as max_post_id  // keep the max post_id in the aggregate
WITH 
    CASE  
        WHEN c > 0 THEN max_post_id + 1  // increment existing post id
        ELSE 1 
    END 
    AS post_id
CREATE (:Post {user_id: 1, post: post_id})
```